# Spreecommerce doen't start correctly in apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

When accessing my ROR **Spree** application I get the following error:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git (at 1-3-stable) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

I did a `bundle install` and `spree_auth_devise` is already installed.
bundle show will contain the following items:

```
  * spree (1.3.2)
  * spree_api (1.3.2)
  * spree_auth_devise (1.0.0 ccd6add)
  * spree_cmd (1.3.2)
  * spree_core (1.3.2)
  * spree_dash (1.3.2)
  * spree_gateway (1.2.0.rc2 556179a)
  * spree_promo (1.3.2)
  * spree_sample (1.3.2)
```

The stack trace:

```
0   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git.rb     177     in `rescue in load_spec_files'
1   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git.rb     175     in `load_spec_files'
2   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/path.rb    86  in `local_specs'
3   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git.rb     150     in `specs'
4   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb     52  in `__materialize__'
5   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   88  in `block in materialize'
6   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   85  in `map!'
7   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   85  in `materialize'
8   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb     114     in `specs'
9   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb     159     in `specs_for'
10  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb     148     in `requested_specs'
11  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb    18  in `requested_specs'
12  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    13  in `setup'
13  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb    120     in `setup'
```

Any idea what could be wrong ? The strange thing is that it works just fine with **rails server**. The issue only appears when using **apache2** and **Passenger**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my application was running correctly in rails server because it used the testing/development gems.

But apache was trying to use the production/deployment gems

I just had to run `bundle install --deployment` to install the production/deployment gems